# turbo/no-undeclared-env-vars not recognizing changes

Tags: next.js, vercel, turborepo

I'm updating my project to use turborepo and I'm encountering a strange behavior with turbo/no-undeclared-env-vars.

In the starter project I added a `hello` constant from the environment variables:

```
export default function Web() {
  const hello = process.env.HELLO;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{hello}</h1>
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And when running `npm run lint` I get the expected error:

```
web:lint: ./pages/index.tsx
web:lint: 4:17  Error: $HELLO is not listed as a dependency in turbo.json  turbo/no-undeclared-env-vars
```

But when I add it to turbo.json and re-run `npm run lint` it still shows the error.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://turborepo.org/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build", "$HELLO"],
      "outputs": ["dist/**", ".next/**"]
    },
    "lint": {
      "outputs": []
    },
    "dev": {
      "cache": false
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to be using the cache because if I remove the cache from `apps/web/.next/.cache/.eslint` and run it again it shows no error anymore.

It also works the other way.
If I now remove the `$HELLO` from `turbo.json` and run `npm run lint` again it says there are not errors, while it should say that it is unlisted. Here as well, removing the cache manually shows it again but it seems to me that it should detect it automatically, no?

I also tried updating `turbo.json` not to use the cache during lint but that is also not helping:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://turborepo.org/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build", "$HELLO"],
      "outputs": ["dist/**", ".next/**"]
    },
    "lint": {
      "outputs": [],
      "cache": false
    },
    "dev": {
      "cache": false
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you still need and answer or if anybody is like me and ended up here googling the issue, the solution was to add a new prop in the build object called `env` so your `turbo.json` would become

```
{
  "$schema": "https://turborepo.org/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "outputs": ["dist/**", ".next/**"],
      "env": [
        "HELLO"
      ]

    },
    "lint": {
      "outputs": [],
      "cache": false
    },
    "dev": {
      "cache": false
    }
  }
}
```

note: no `$` prefix needed.

When running turborepo on Vercel you also get some extra useful info like a codemod to fix your `turbo.json` file in your case by running

```
npx @turbo/codemod migrate-env-var-dependencies
```

in the root folder you'd get the right props in the json file.

One last thing, if you're using next and turborepo, your ENV vars, if they are needed in the frontend like your example, should be prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` so in your case

```
const hello = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HELLO;
```

with that change, turborepo will know that you're using that env var as part of a next project and the caching algorithm will behave accordingly

Comment: https://turbo.build/repo/docs/core-concepts/caching#automatic-environment-variable-inclusion

Comment: Thank you, the env prop was indeed added after I asked the question and seems to fix the issue.